# A metric on $Homeo([0,1])$

Tags: gr.group-theory, fa.functional-analysis

One can define a metric on the set $Homeo([0,1])$ by setting $dist(f,g) =$ measure of support of $f^{-1}g$, that is the measure of the set of points $x$ where $f(x)\ne g(x)$. Was this metric studied and if so how is it called?

Comment: Check out "uniform topology", "uniform metric". This is widely used (but not specifically on the homeomorphism group, since this has little to do with the topology). In a paper of Carderi and Le Maître, they refer to Halmos's 1960 book "Lectures in ergodic theory" for this topology.

Comment: By the way your definition is a bit ambiguous. The support of $h$ is usually defined (in this group context) as the **closure** of $\{x:h(x)\neq x\}$; this can be greater than the measure of the open subset $\{x:h(x)\neq x\}$; I can't guess which definition you have in mind; my previous comment rather refers to the latter definition.

Comment: By the way, for either choice of the definition of "support" (see my previous comment), if $f(x)=(x+h(x))/2$ where $h$ is the Cantor function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), then $u\mapsto u^{-1}$ is not continuous at $f$ in this topology. In particular, this does not provide a group topology.

Comment: We need the metric not on the whole Homeo but on the Thompson group $F$ viewed as a subgroup of Homeo[(0,1]). In that case the measures of  support and the closure of support are the same, and both group operations are continuous.